PostgreSQL Вывести данные за последние 3 месяца с даты отсчета
Есть табличка с пользователями и табличка с операциями.
Нужно написать скрипт который выводит помесячно количество неактивных пользователей(пользователи которые не совершали операции на протяжении 3-х месяцев).
Совсем не понимаю как это сделать за 3 месяца, итог должен быть такой

2024-01-31: N неактивных пользователей
2024-02-29: N неактивных пользователей
2024-03-31: N неактивных пользователей
2024-04-30: N неактивных пользователей

И тд

Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL? Пункты 5 и 3.

Совсем не понимаю как это сделать за 3 месяца Оконный COUNT, фрейм за предыдущие три месяца, и сравнить с нулём.

Мне это мало, что говорит… Я не понимаю как такую оконную функцию сделать

Читать по ссылке. Потом пример - в студию.
